# Access values in JSON based on a condition using Groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy, httpresponse, jsonslurper

I am trying to extract two sets of information from the httpResponse (in the form of JSON)- 
1. Location 
2. city where fruit = Apple and luckyNumber = 10.

```
{
    "userInformation": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Location": "India"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "fruit": "Apple",
            "color": "Red",
            "city": "New Delhi",
            "luckyNumber": 10
        },
        {
            "fruit": "Banana",
            "color": "yellow",
            "city": "Goa",
            "luckyNumber": 12
         }
         ]
         }
```

For extracting the Location, I tried the below code:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(httpResponse)

userLocation = slurper.userInformation.Location
```

This gives me an error -

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[statusCode:200, reason:OK, headers:[Access-Control-Allow-Credential:true, ...], ...]] Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse([B), parse([C), parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error

```
No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for
       argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap)
Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), ...
```

means that you try to pass Map (`httpResponse`) into `JsonSlurper.parseText()` when this method accepts String.

Find how to get response body as a string and then you can use JsonSlurper.parseText()

Comment: Can you help me how can I convert response body to string? I tried below code, but doesn't work:            
def jsonBody = new JsonBuilder(httpResponse).toString()
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonBody)

Comment: There's no need for to `String` conversion. You already have a `Map` and can work with it.

Comment: @ComplexData, could you show the code you use to get http response.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need httpResponse.getData() or just httpResponse.data to access response data payload. This data may already be in map, if response was parsed correctly based on Content-Type, in this case you do not need to use JsonSlurper. If data is a json String then use JsonSlurper.

In any case you will have something like

```
def cities = responseData.details.findAll{it.fruit=="Apple" && it.luckyNumber==10}
```